# Kivy video player won't show video, but plays audio

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to make an application which downloads a video using Pytube, after getting it from a search using youtube-search-python, then playing the video using Kivy's video player. Everything works fine, except for playing the video.
Here is my code:

```
from pytube import YouTube
from kivy.app import App
from youtubesearchpython import VideosSearch
from kivy.uix.videoplayer import VideoPlayer

videosSearch = VideosSearch('心臓を捧げよ！', limit = 1)

for i in range(1):
    download_link = videosSearch.result()['result'][i]['link']
    

yt = YouTube(download_link)
yt.streams.get_highest_resolution().download()
video = (yt.title) + '.mp4'

class Player(VideoPlayer):
   player = VideoPlayer(source= video, state = 'play')


class VideoApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Player()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    VideoApp().run()
```

and here is my output:

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Shahzad\.kivy\logs\kivy_23-03-30_14.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.1.0
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.10.9 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Jan 11 2023, 15:15:40) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\ProgramData\miniconda3\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge log fired. Processing...
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 189 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [ImageLoaderFFPy] Using ffpyplayer 4.4.0
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil, img_ffpyplayer 
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [VideoFFPy   ] Using ffpyplayer 4.4.0
[INFO   ] [Video       ] Provider: ffpyplayer(['video_ffmpeg'] ignored)
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.6.0 Compatibility Profile Context 23.3.1.230305'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'ATI Technologies Inc.'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'AMD Radeon(TM) Vega 3 Graphics '>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 6
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.60'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[ERROR  ] [Image       ] Error loading <【MAD】『心臓を捧げよ！』で振り返る 進撃の巨人 Season 2.mp4>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] NPOT texture support is available
```

I installed ffpyplayer after seeing that worked for some people with a slightly different error. Doing so caused me to get audio, but still no video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing:

```
return Player()
```

with:

```
return VideoPlayer(source= video, state = 'play')
```

and eliminate the `Player` class.

Comment: **edit**: I tried again with the widget and instead of declaring what had to be played, I just put 'pass' and used the return code provided, and it worked exactly the same